# What is a work around for displaying empty <p> tags inside contenteditable div?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, contenteditable, nicedit

This is for Internet Explorer only.
I have a content editable div in which my users enter rich content (nicEditor).

I have functionality where I set the html of the div with predefined templates. 
Ideally I would like my templates to be like.

```
<p><b>My Heading1</b></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p><b>My Heading2</b></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p><b>My Heading3</b></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

Where it renders like

> **My Heading1**
>   *blankline*
>   *blankline*
>   **My Heading2**
>   *blankline*
>   *blankline*
>   **My Heading3**
>   *blankline*
>   *blankline*

However it renders like so.

> **My Heading1**
>   **My Heading2**
>   **My Heading3**

I've tried using these instead but there are issues with all of them.
`<p>&nbsp;</p>`, `<p><span style="display:none;">&nbsp;</span></p>` - Always a space on each line.
`<p><br/></p>` - When a user starts typing a new line appears.
`<br/>`, `<span><br/></span>` - Works for spacing except when a user uses one of the insert list commands. And all the content is put under a single list item.

What can I do to have my `<p>` tags display in my div?

Comment: What's the line-height on P elements? You can also try doing a regex replace like text = text.replace(/<p><\/p>/gim, '<br />');

Comment: @Vibhu I can't use `<br/>` tags alone due to the issue when a user tries to insert a list.

Comment: I tried `&nbsp;` and it works ok http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/nYmHJ/

Comment: try using &nbsp; in the p's

Comment: @Kev I tried in other browsers and I get the space on every line in them as well. This is inside a contenteditable div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had success in using `<P>&#8203;</P>` The Zero Width Space character. However, this makes it so that if a user wishes to delete a line they must press backspace twice. I'm going to ask a new question to address that.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886006/how-can-i-detect-when-character-to-be-deleted-is-zero-width-space-and-execute-de)