# How can I detect when character to be deleted is Zero Width Space and execute delete or backspace command twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a content editable div in which I am using the zero width space character in order to make my `<p></p>` tags visible and not contain a space character.

Like so

```
<div id="myeditor" contenteditable="true">
    <p><b>My Heading 1</b></p>
    <p>&#8203;</p>
    <p>&#8203;</p>
    <p>&#8203;</p>
    <p><b>My Heading 2</b></p>
    <p>&#8203;</p>
    <p>&#8203;</p>
    <p>&#8203;</p>
    <p><b>My Heading 3</b></p>
    <p>&#8203;</p>
    <p>&#8203;</p>
    <p>&#8203;</p>
</div>
```

This works well except that the user must press backspace twice or delete twice when trying to delete content on the other side of the `ZWSP` character.

I want to be able to detect that I am about to delete the `ZWSP` and either remove it before the delete executes or execute the delete command twice. How can I do this? I also need this to work in internet explorer...

So far I have

```
$(document).on('keydown', "#myeditor", function (e) {
    var keyPressed = e.keyCode | e.which;
    if(keyPressed == 8 || keyPressed == 46){
        //TODO: determine character to be deleted and remove it if it is ZWSP
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working.

```
$(document).on('keydown', "#myeditor", function (e) {
    var keyPressed = e.keyCode | e.which;
    if(keyPressed == 8){
       //TODO: determine character to be deleted and remove it if it is ZWSP
       var range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.moveStart('character', -1);
        if(range.text === String.fromCharCode(8203))
        {
            range.text = "";
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's far from being perfect, but it might give you a kick-start. Have a look here http://jsbin.com/eweqon/3/edit

The idea is to determine if the character we are about to delete is within a `textNode` that only contains `&#8203;` characters. If it does, we further check if it's `parentNode` is a `p` tag and that tag only contains a single `textNode`. If all the conditions are fulfilled, we safely remove the `p` tag from it's parent. It seems to work well, however, I am not sure how to handle the case where the `p` tag contains other children elements.

```
$(document).on('keydown', "#myeditor", function (e) {
var keyPressed = e.keyCode | e.which,
    emptyCharsOnly = true,
    node,
    range,
    i,
    len,
    text,
    p;
if(keyPressed == 8 || keyPressed == 46){
    //TODO: determine character to be deleted and remove it if it is ZWSP
  range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  node = range.startContainer;
  p = node.parentNode;
  text = node.wholeText;

  if (!text) {
    return;
  }

  len = text.length;

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (text.charCodeAt(i) !== 8203) {
      emptyCharsOnly = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (
    node.nodeType === 3 &&
    emptyCharsOnly &&
    p && p.tagName === 'P'
  ) {

    //make sure the p tag only contains this text node
    if (p.childNodes.length === 1) {
      p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
    } else {
      //not sure what to do here exactly
      //i tried removing the previousSibling but it
      //did not give expected results.
    }
  }
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider changing the markup you provide instead, especially as when your users add blank lines, they're not going to end up with an paragraph containing an zero width space.

A quick experiment shows Firefox uses a <br/>, and Chrome uses <div><br/></div>. I think you'd probably be best off using <br/> instead of paragraph tags. However you'll need to do more experimenting than I have to be sure.

Comment: I can't use <br/> tags unfortunately as they do not play nice with inserting lists.

Comment: Try the Chrome style then, a div containing a br. I think you're going to be better off using a style that matches what one of the browsers uses for an empty line.

Comment: Crafting a cross-browser solution will not be easy since the markup generated is up to the browser's implementation. Have you considered using well-know editors such as TinyMCE?

Comment: @plalx TinyMCE is too slow for my purposes (I'm actually using a heavilly modified version of NicEdit). I only care about internet explorer for browser.

Comment: So if you clear your content editable and press enter, what does IE put in there? Use that for your blank line.

Comment: @SamStephens I tried using `<div><br/></div>` and I have to press delete or backspace several times before a visible delete occurs. IE uses `<p>` for new lines and I can't use those for my templates as browsers do not render empty `<p>` tags which leaves me with using `<p>&#8203;</p>`.

Comment: @BiffMaGriff If you want to see empty `<p>` tags, cant you just put a CSS class on them and give them some height or something similar?

Comment: @plalx No unfortunatly. `User agents should ignore empty P elements.` http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1

Comment: But surely they render properly within the contenteditable if IE puts them there? Could you put empty P elements in the editable, and transform them into something else for use outside the editable?